# Should I purchase a switch, a hub, or a router?

Tags: networking, router, switch, hub

I have just installed a Motorola SURFboard SBG901 cable modem, and I can connect two computers I have to the Internet via Wifi. I'd like to distribute the Internet connection among some other machines through Ethernet instead, in an inexpensive way.

I've done some research on the Web, but I have found the answer for this in random forums, which seem to contradict each other. In one of them, I read that the simplest is a network switch, while in others I read that a switch will require me to maintain a central server, and then I should purchase a router instead. The Wikipedia articles on *Network switch* and *Router* have left my head spinning!

I have noticed that in the SURFboard there is no way to change the DNS servers, and it also doesn't seem to hold a DNS cache. Is it possible to have these without a central server?

Also, does a switch, hub, or router generally have some kind of bandwidth control?

The most important for me is to know what should I purchase just to share access via Ethernet with these machines. Regarding the DNS and bandwidth control, they would be desirable, but not a priority, so a small comparison between how a switch, hub, or a router would apply *in my case* would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget a Hub as it's like the technology before switches. It has a use for packet sniffing but you don't want it for that. Switches are often called intelligent hubs. They're both equally  easy to use (plug in and use) so get the switch.

If you already have 2 computers running on your motorola then that device is a NAT Router, but if there is only one socket for attaching a wired device then you should get a switch, which you plug into the one wired socket and it will give you more sockets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, the Motorola has only one socket. The DNS thing I don't think it would... but would a switch provide some kind of bandwidth control?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior i'm no expert on bandwidth control.The switch I use is cheap so nope.A Router might be more likely to offer bandwidth control but ones i've bought have been too cheap to,maybe an expensive one will.u could also consider some bandwidth control via software on the potentially offending computer itself i've heard of softperfect bandwidth manager which i've seen used for another purpose but looked simple to configure.I haven't really tried bandwidth control so cant advise much on good ways of doing it. Maybe DDWRT or Tomato can. They r firmware upgrades compatible with some routers.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior  If you have a router that supports DDWRT. (the router is basically a little linux machine as so many consumer devices are), but one that supports it. This is a video that shows how to do bandwidth control "Using DD-WRT for Bandwidth Control"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjCb5P302Ms    Flicking through the video it looks like he tests it neatly.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior  http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=61801&sid=fdd6d876024c90f0ff05b42f2996fbce  (somebody posted in 2009) "Motorola  SBG900/SBG901 cable modems are part of the Motorola Surfboard SeriesAndAreConsideredCable modems.TheyDoSupport 3rd party firmwaresAnd a JTAG connection but DD-WRT is not compatible with them unless u recompile it with drivers and modificationsFor support."I see some motorola modems listed in the database http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database  but not an SBG 900/901.It may b possible but with some extra fiddling.dd-wrt forum wud know re that

Comment: Thanks, @barlop! I don't know whether I can mess up with the firmware, because the modem is not mine (it belongs to the ISP). Unless I can return to the original one later. But Tomato sounds delicious :P

Comment: @TeresaeJunior I'd recommend a router if you're only going to connect a few other computers via ethernet and its a very versatile solution. Like the others have said you do want a router thats compatible with DDWRT, OPENWRT, or Tomato can. I have the Asus N66u which comes with a custom version of OPENWRT installed and its perfect for all the devices that I have on my network as well as having bandwidth control features. I'd consider this optimal for connecting <4 devices via ethernet. Any more and you may want to look into a switch.

Comment: @slow_excellence So basically just for sharing the connection in an inexpensive way, I need a switch. If I want more features, I need to buy a router or install a new firmware on the modem/router, right?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Thats pretty much the gist of it. You don't HAVE to install 3rd party firmware onto the new router, but it's highly recommended since the developers usually have their s**t together. I'm also biased against the Motorola SURFboard modem/router combos which is why I recommended a separate router (ATT provided modem/router was a POS and would drop the connection to the ISP if more than 5 devices were using the internet at once). A switch will be much cheaper but won't have the features you're looking for.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior You write " If I want more features, I need to buy a router or install a new firmware on the modem/router, right? " <-- Not really right.  Even if you buy a router it's typically not going to have any bandwidth control so you'd put ddwrt on it.  You have to check that the new router supports ddwrt.   But it looks like https://flashrouters.zendesk.com/entries/27079824-Why-Can-t-I-Use-DD-WRT-or-Tomato-with-an-ADSL-Modem-Router-   looks like using a  DDWRT device, you have to have another device to act as modem.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Your current cable modem would have to be put in "bridge mode" and it's not a straight forward option, but it looks like there are some options that do it.   http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Home-Networking-Router-WiFi/Motorola-sbg901-bridging-mode/td-p/921289   The idea is that the device with the modem doesn't do NAT. That way you won't have double NAT. Though if you do have double NAT that can work but it's unnecessarily messy.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior So if you want bandwidth control, and you take the ddwrt route it may be advisable to get a new router and new modem. A Router that supports ddwrt. And a modem that can be put in bridge mode.  Your one device could potentially be used, then you'd only have to buy one more device, but your device(which does both router and modem) is problematic as a modem(tricky to go into bridge mode) and problematic as a router(fiddly to get ddwrt support from it). Though getting it into bridge mode might not be that hard, that link in the comment above shows somebody that did it.

Comment: @barlop Thanks, I think I understand it now! You have confirmed what I suspected. I think it is possible to put this modem in bridge mode, doesn't seem so difficult from what I've read.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior ok then you just need to buy a new router.For now  Set modem to bridge and to test that it's in bridge mode..or rather,at least,not doing NAT.Try to connect to the Internet with it,open a cmd prompt(start..run..cmd<ENTER>) do the ipconfig command `C:\>ipconfig<ENTER>` see what the IP is.If it's private e.g. 192.168.. or 10.x.y.z or 172...Or if it's public. Then do `C:\>tracert www.google.com`and see that there is no private address. n make sure your firewall is on, and do a port scan e.g. "shields up" at www.grc.com to make sure ur computer isn't found by that 2 have open ports!

Comment: @barlop Thanks for the instructions, they'll come in handy!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15498/discussion-between-barlop-and-teresa-e-junior).